Umbraco: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_cmsPropertyType_umbracoDataType_node_id
I recently upgraded my Umbraco website from 13 to 14. It seems that I have duplications that remained from when I upgraded from 7 to 8. I try to remove these duplicates in my database, but getting the following error:
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_cmsPropertyType_umbracoDataType_node_id

How can I remove the duplicates fields?
Will it delete data from other tables?
(by sql command or through the SQL server)
What I try to remove is the Media picker from version 7
But also wants to make sure I don't delete the information from the database (it's a magazine website and I don't want to delete old content).
Thanks.
